# Bounty not received after grace period?

Tags: discussion, support

A week ago I've answered a question that had a bounty of +50 on it. Just after the grace period, my answer was accepted on the question:

[Full Secure Image Upload Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509334/full-secure-image-upload-script)

I did receive the normal reputation for the answer, but didn't receive any bounty at all. I think this happened because the answer was accepted after the grace period, but if that's true, isn't this a design flaw? I mean, that way anyone can just promise some extra reputation to get their question answered and then just ignore it untill after the grace period so they don't actually have to give that rep.

Answer (score 3):

At the time that the bounty ended your answer had a score of zero and was not accepted, and so didn't qualify as an automatic recipient of the bounty in the event that the bounty owner didn't award it.  There were no other answers that did meet the qualifications, so the bounty wasn't awarded to any answer.

Comment: Thanks, that was all I needed to know :) I didn't know about the auto-award on +2 upvotes so the system can't really be abused.